# Laravel - how to re-use functions that are passing models in functions as parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to understand further how I can harness the power of this feature where one could pass a model as an empty object which is already instantiated and ready for use.

The problem I'm facing is re-usability, I do not want to write the function twice.

So let's take for instance the following function:

**API**

```
Route::post('/onboarding/email-verification', 'CustomerController@verifyEmail');
```

**Controller**

```
public function verifyEmail(Request $request, Customer $customer) {}
```

The function above serves a simple purpose, it allows me to use the `Request` instance I am already receiving from the http request, where I have an instantiated object as `$request`, where I can make further use of.

Now in the same controller, I am looking to use `verifyEmail()`, as `$this->verifyEmail()` but I can't, since the function is expecting 2 params, I tried rebuilding the function like:

`$this->verifyEmail(new Request(['email' => $customer->email]), new Customer())` - since the function expects an email. I tried many other iteration but even if they did work, they look horrendous.

So my question is simple, how can you re-use a Laravel function that is built with models/objects in it's params.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a third parameter :

```
public function verifyEmail(Request $request, Customer $customer, ?string Email)
{
      if ($email) {
         // use var
      } else {
         // use request
      }
}
```

And you just inject Request to use it, or make $request parameter nullable :

```
$this->verifyEmail($request, new Customer(), 'youremail@test.com')
```

If you want to keep your 2 parameters, you can define new $request variable like this :

```
$request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
$request->replace(['email' => 'email@totest.com']);

$this->verifyEmail($request, new Customer());
```

Comment: I like your answer v.much and it serves the basic purpose, yet though this whole empty model param is a framework 'thing', I was hoping to see a framework solve for this in a more elegant construct which is part of the FW, since the example I gave in my OP is extremely basic. If no one will give any answer for a week, your the answer (that works) thanks Vincent.

Comment: It's basic OOP Php here, the framework can't override this. I updated my answer with other solution if you prefer

Comment: Ok then, yours.